# How to implement equivalent of setUserInteractionEnabled: for UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibarbuttonitem

`UIBarButtonItem` has a `setEnabled:` method which (for all but the back button) works as expected, but it does not have a `setUserInteractionEnabled:` method. But while not enabled, `UIBarButtonItems` can receive touches which, when re-enabled, they attempt to process. I'd like to do the equivalent of `setUserInteractionEnabled: NO`  for my navigation bar buttons (during an operation that can sometimes take a while).

Is there an easy way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: May you could put a transparent view on top of the item which catches all touches when it's not hidden. Hide it, if you wan't the BarButtonItem to react.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do little customization and you can do it...

// Add this code in your viewDidLoad

```
UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];   
[leftButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
leftButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yorrmethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];        
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton];
[leftButton release];

UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[rightButton setUserInteractionEnabled : NO];
[rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
rightButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourmethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];        
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButton];
[rightButton release];
```

Hope,this will help you...

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Clearly this is one route to go. But it would mean having to make a custom back button that mimics the iOS standard one. Do-able, but if avoidable, I'd rather avoid it.